# How to wait for an async query to finish in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the result of an async function - depending on the result I either want to execute another function or continue the for loop. Here is my Cloud Function:

```
return query.get().then(geoSnapshot => {
        // If GeoquerySnapshot returns 0 docs, createDoc()
        let docs = geoSnapshot.docs;
        if (docs.length === 0) return createDoc(data);
        for(let [index, doc] of docs.entries()){
            // If age preferences are valid, joinDoc
            let currentDoc = docs[index].data();
            if (validAge(currentDoc, data)){
                let matchedBefore = await(matchedBefore(currentDoc, data))
                if (!matchedBefore){
                    return joinDoc(docs[index], data);
                } else if (index === (docs.length - 1)) {
                    return createDoc(data);
                }
            }
            return
        }
    }).catch( error => {
        console.log("error query: " + error);
        return { error: error };
    })

async function matchedBefore(currentDoc, data){
    return db.collection('users').doc(data.uid).get().then( doc => {
        if ( !doc.exists ) return false;
        // If user1 in matchedUsers
        let matchedUsers = doc.get('matchedUsers');
        if (matchedUsers === undefined) return true
        let matchedBefore = matchedUsers.includes(currentDoc.user1);
        console.log('matchedBefore: ' + matchedBefore);
        if (matchedBefore) { 
            return false 
        } else {
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

I'm getting this following error on `let matchedBefore = await(matchedBefore(currentDoc, data))`:

```
Each then() should return a value or throw
```

How can I ensure the function `matchedBefore()` finishes before the for loop continues?

Comment: try to use one by one promise as per your requirement here you are making multiple calls like validAge , joinDoc in one then block it is not right way

Comment: validAge() is a syncronous function, not a promise @PrakashKarena

Comment: what about createDoc ??

Comment: Also synchronous @PrakashKarena - matchedBefore() is the only async function

Comment: its valid to use await as function instead as operator? imo `await(matchedBefore(currentDoc, data))` should look like `await matchedBefore(currentDoc, data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are too confused with the implementation of async-await. The correct way would be:

```js
return query.get().then(async geoSnapshot => {
  // If GeoquerySnapshot returns 0 docs, createDoc()
  let docs = geoSnapshot.docs;
  if (docs.length === 0) return createDoc(data);
  /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
  for(let [index, doc] of docs.entries()) {
    // If age preferences are valid, joinDoc
    let currentDoc = docs[index].data();

    if (validAge(currentDoc, data)){
      let matchedBefore = await(matchedBefore(currentDoc, data))
      if (!matchedBefore){
          return joinDoc(docs[index], data);
      } else if (index === (docs.length - 1)) {
          return createDoc(data);
      }
    }
    return
  }
  /* eslint-enable no-await-in-loop */
}).catch( error => {
    console.log("error query: " + error);
    return { error: error };
})

async function matchedBefore(currentDoc, data){
  let doc = await db.collection('users').doc(data.uid).get()
  
  if ( !doc.exists ) return false;

  // If user1 in matchedUsers
  let matchedUsers = doc.get('matchedUsers');
  if (matchedUsers === undefined) return true

  let matchedBefore = matchedUsers.includes(currentDoc.user1);
  console.log('matchedBefore: ' + matchedBefore);

  return !matchedBefore
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error on your code: `Unexpected await inside a loop`

Comment: It's not a bug but just a linting error. Check the updated code. :)